# What is /i in navigator.userAgent.match

Tags: javascript, user-agent, navigator

I'm curious what `/i` is in:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }};
}
```

Source: https://www.sitepoint.com/navigator-useragent-mobiles-including-ipad/

Could anyone tell me what `/i` is exactly? I've searched a lot of websites for things about the navigator.userAgent.Match but none explain what `/i` is, sometimes it also is `/g`

Comment: Case-insensitive flag. So the pattern matches *Android*, *androiD*, or *anDrOid* etc.

Comment: so /i means that it's not sensitive to lower and uppercases, but can I replace /i with any other character?

Comment: No, you cannot. That's it by design.

Comment: I found some people use /g does that have a meaning, or is that just incorrect?

Comment: `g` flag catches multiple matches in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/heregoesregex/flags` is literal for Regular Expression in  many languages (including javascript). After the last slash you can specify flags for regular expression. List of available flags for javascript includes:

- **g**    Global search.
- **i**    Case-insensitive search.
- **m**    Multi-line search.
- **y**    "sticky" search that matches starting at the current
  position in the target string

Comment: Note that ES6 also supports `/u` for unicode support.